How can I parse the data from a Table On a Google Docs Using Python?
I need to parse the data contained in a table on a Google Doc that looks like so:

This code:
import requests

def retrieve_parse_and_print_doc(docURL):
    response = requests.get(docURL)
    assert response.status_code == 200, 'Wrong status code'
    lines = response.content.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)

retrieve_parse_and_print_doc('https://docs.google.com/document/...[elided]/pub')

...returned data, but it doesn't appear to be useful:

So how can I extract the table's data?

From your URL, I guessed that your Google Document has been published as the Web publish. If my understanding is correct, I guessed that you might want to achieve without the authorization process. Is my guess correct? And, in your situation, has your Google Document also been publicly shared? Or, if it has never been publicly shared, can you do it? I thought that the approach would depend on the situation.

You should set up Google API then use Google Doc API for that.
According to the REST Resource: documents you can return a table object :

"table": {object (Table)}
table object (Table) : A table type of structural element.


I think the best way to do this is to use pandas.read_html. It will read the table into a dataframe directly. Something like:
import pandas as pd

url = "https://docs.google.com/document/...[elided]/pub"
df = pd.read_html(url, encoding='utf-8')
print(df[0])

You need the utf-8 encoding to display the special characters correctly. You will get something like this:
 0  x-coordinate  Character  y-coordinate
 1            87          █             3
 2            23          ░             2
 3            61          █             4
 [etc.]


I was faced with this same exact problem. I'm going to guess you and I were probably doing the same application challenge! This question was also asked here, but I'll copy my solution here as well since it hasn't yet been marked as a duplicate. Also, I'm making the assumption that you, like me, did not want to use the Google API because you didn't want to have to deal with authenticating. If authentication tokens are not an issue, that definitely seems like the tidiest way to go about it.
Using requests, I was able to pull down the raw HTML response from calling the page, then using BeautifulSoup I was able to turn it into a workable, parse-able object:
# Make request
html_response = requests.get(url=url)

# Parse html into a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_response.text, 'html.parser')

# Collect and return the first table (assuming the first table is what you want)
return soup.find('table')

From there, you can parse the table more precisely to pull out the data you want. Here are a couple examples of how you can work with a BeautifulSoup table to get what you need:

https://pytutorial.com/how-to-extract-data-from-tables-using-beautifulsoup/
https://pytutorial.com/understand-how-to-work-with-table-in-beautifulsoup/

I'm refraining from copy-pasting my exact solution because I know others will use this to fill out the same job application challenge, but this gets you everything you need as long as you have a Python foundation.
